# Using checkboxes to filter records PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am a PHP and MySQL novice, so please keep your answers simple!!!

I have a database that lists a bunch of retirement communities and the services they offer. I have a series of fields using a boolean (tinyint) and if they offer the service, they get a 1. If they don't they get a 0.

I have it display fine, but now I am trying to filter the list using checkboxes. I am also searching by City and State (which work) but once I add my code for the checkboxes, it fails. It just shows all the records no matter what. Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<fieldset><legend>Filter</legend>
    <p><label>City:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="by_city" /></p>
    <p><label>State:&nbsp;</label><input type="text" name="by_state" /></p>
    <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="IndependentLiving" value="1" />    Independent Living<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="AssistedLiving" value="1" /> Assisted Living<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="SkilledNursing" value="1" /> Skilled Nursing<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="MemoryCare" value="1" /> Memory Care<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ContinuingCareCommunity" value="1" /> Continuing Care Community<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Respite" value="1" />  Short-term/Respite<br>
    </p>
    <p><input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" /></p>
</fieldset>     
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
$by_city = $_POST['by_city'];
$by_state = $_POST['by_state'];
$IndependentLiving = $_POST['IndependentLiving'];
$AssistedLiving = $_POST['AssistedLiving'];
$SkilledNursing = $_POST['SkilledNursing'];
$MemoryCare = $_POST['MemoryCare'];
$ContinuingCareCommunity = $_POST['ContinuingCareCommunity'];
$Respite = $_POST['Respite'];



mysql_select_db('CommunityList');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$query = "SELECT * FROM Communities WHERE (City='$by_city') OR (State='$by_state') OR (IndependentLiving='$IndependentLiving') OR (AssistedLiving='$AssistedLiving') OR (SkilledNursing='$SkilledNursing') OR (MemoryCare='$MemoryCare') OR (ContinuingCareCommunity='$ContinuingCareCommunity') OR (Respite='$Respite')";
}
else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM Communities";
}
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Checkboxes are only posted if they are checked. So you need to set a default value, ie. `0` when it is not checked. You could use a ternary to do this. ie. `$IndependentLiving = isset($_POST['IndependentLiving']) ? $_POST['IndependentLiving'] : 0;`. This says if `$_POST['IndependentLiving']` is set, ie. `name="IndependentLiving"` was checked, use its value. if not, then use `0` as the value.

Comment: Also, typically if you want to filter using these checkboxes, you would use `AND IndependentLiving=1`, so that it requires that value. So another alternative is to only add these filters when they are checked, and remove them from the query when unchecked.

Comment: Seeing `action=""` implies you're using your entire code in the same file and you should be getting undefined index notices *right off the bat*. So, you'll need to adjust your code as per answer(s) given if they haven't mentioned it/compensated for it. Error reporting will tell you that http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

You are using `OR` in your `SELECT` query which means OR, so if at least one WHERE matches, the record will be returned.

What you can is:

```
$postToColumnMaps = array('by_city' => 'City', 'by_state' => 'State');
$sqlWhereParts = array();
foreach ($postToColumnMaps as $postKey => $columnKey) {
    if (strlen($_POST[$postKey]) > 0) {
        $sqlWhereParts[] = $columnKey . ' = \'' . $_POST[$postKey] . '\'';
    }
}

$sqlWhere = implode(' AND ', $sqlWhereParts);
```

you can use this filter then like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Communities WHERE " . $sqlWhere;
```

Just to get an idea, I coded it without testing. Be also aware of SQL injection, at least the `$_POST[$postKey]` needs to be escaped.